# Dynamic data with ionic framework

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new in using ionic framework.
I'm using an exemple to display contactss in my application in services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', []).factory('Equipements', function() {
    var equipements = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Scruff McGruff'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'G.I. Joe'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Miss Frizzle'
    }];
    return {
        all: function() {
            return equipements;
        },
        get: function(equipId) {
            // Simple index lookup
            return equipements[equipId];
        }
    }
})
```

But I wanna use a resource that returns a JSON array from my MySQL database.

Is it possible with ionic ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

```
angular.module('starter.services', []).factory('Equipements', function($http) {
    var equipements = {};
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/get_all_equipments'
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        equipements = data;
    });
    return {
        all: function() {
            return equipements;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got an error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load my URL. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. What's wrong ?

Comment: it's problem from your back end, server side